# Dropzone.js progressbar not updating on emit using s3.managedUpload

Tags: dropzone.js, aws-sdk-js

I found a couple of examples on how to do AWS uploads with dropzone.js testing them independently and now I'm trying to combine them into a finished form for our website's image uploader.

The one example I found showed that you could trigger progress updates from the S3.managedUpload as follows:

```
file.s3upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
    if (progress.total) {
        var percent = ((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total);
        console.log('httpUploadProgress', percent, progress.loaded);
        myDropzone.emit('uploadprogress', file, percent, progress.loaded);
    }
});
```

With my console.log in there, I can see multiple loops of the httpUploadProgress with increasing percentage. But the {dropzone}.emit doesn't seem to update the progress bar.

I've tried using the external 'myDropzone' var as well as making my AWSSendFile function (where the above code is included) as a prototype of dropzone itself so I can refer to it with this.emit(). No luck.

The dropzone template is:

```
dropzoneTemplate:'
<div class="Item dropzone-previews">
  <div class="Icon"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
  <div class="Description dz-preview dz-file-preview">
    <span class="Filename" data-dz-name ></span><br/>
    <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload dz-progress" data-dz-uploadprogress ></span></div>
  </div>
</div>'
```

Full code with the prototyped functions:

```
// override the uploadFiles function to send via AWS SDK instead of xhr
Dropzone.prototype.uploadFiles = function (files) {
    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
        var file = files[j];
        this.AWSsendFile(file);
    }
};
Dropzone.prototype.AWSsendFile = function(file) {
    let dz = this;
    file.s3upload.send(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            dz.emit("error", file, err.message);
        } else {
            dz.emit("complete", file);
        }
    });

    // listen to the AWS httpUploadProgress event, and emit an equivalent Dropzone event
    file.s3upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
        if (progress.total) {
            var percent = ((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total);
            console.log('httpUploadProgress', percent, progress.loaded);
            dz.emit('uploadprogress', file, percent, progress.loaded);
        }
    });
};

function acceptCallback(file, done) {
    // options for the managed upload for this accepted file
    // define the bucket, and the S3 key the file will be stored as
    let fullKey = userId + "/" + file.name;
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fullKey,
        Body: file,
        Region: 'us-east-2'
    };
    // add an S3 managed upload instance to the file
    file.s3upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({params: params});
    done();
};
function abortUpload(file) {
    if (file.s3upload) file.s3upload.abort();
};
```

example console.log data:

```
   httpUploadProgress 97.33840304182509 49152 
   httpUploadProgress 100 50496
```

UPDATE:
I noticed one problem with the async embedded callbacks and modified the 'prototyped' functions above to show my changes. Setting a local variable for dz = this to hold the handle of the main dropzone object. This makes the progress bar work hunky-dory and it now goes to 100%, but now the 'complete' emit call doesn't seem to be telling it to show as complete.

Comment: pending update - I solved one problem but still have another....

Comment: Updated to reflect the partial fix and new issue. It seems the s3upload (ManagedUpload) .send(callback) is never triggering the callback.